# Get unique values of a column in between a timeperiod in pandas after groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

I have a requirement where I need to find all the unique values of a merchant_store_id of the user on the same stampcard in between a specific time period. I had group by stampcard id and userid to get the data frame based on the condition. Now I need to find the unique merchant_store_id of the this dataframe in interval of 10mins from that entry.

My approach is I would loop in that groupby dataframe and then I would find the all indexes in that dataframe of that group and then I would create a new dataframe from time of index to index + 60mins and then find the unique merchant_store_id's in it. If the unique merchant_store_id is >1 , I would append that dataframe from that time to a final dataframe. Problem with the approach is it works fine for small data, but for data of size 20,000 rows it shows memory error on linux and keeps on running on windows. Below is my code

```
fi_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in df.groupby(["stamp_card_id", "merchant_id", "user_id"]):
    user_df = i[1]
    if len(user_df)>1:
        # get list of unique indexes in that groupby df
        index = user_df.index.values
        for ind in index:
            fdf = user_df[ind:ind+np.timedelta64(1, 'h')]
            if len(fdf.merchant_store_id.unique())>1:
                fi_df=fi_df.append(fdf)
fi_df.drop_duplicates(keep="first").to_csv(csv_export_path)
```

Sample Data after group by is:

```
((117, 209, 'oZOfOgAgnO'),     stamp_card_id          stamp_time  stamps_record_id     user_id  \
0             117 2018-10-14 16:48:03              1756  oZOfOgAgnO   
1             117 2018-10-14 16:54:03              1759  oZOfOgAgnO   
2             117 2018-10-14 16:58:03              1760  oZOfOgAgnO   
3             117 2018-10-14 17:48:03              1763  oZOfOgAgnO   
4             117 2018-10-14 18:48:03              1765  oZOfOgAgnO   
5             117 2018-10-14 19:48:03              1767  oZOfOgAgnO   
6             117 2018-10-14 20:48:03              1769  oZOfOgAgnO   
7             117 2018-10-14 21:48:03              1771  oZOfOgAgnO   
8             117 2018-10-15 22:48:03              1773  oZOfOgAgnO   
9             117 2018-10-15 23:08:03              1774  oZOfOgAgnO   
10            117 2018-10-15 23:34:03              1777  oZOfOgAgnO   

    merchant_id  merchant_store_id  
0           209                662  
1           209                662  
2           209                662  
3           209                662  
4           209                662  
5           209                662  
6           209                663  
7           209                664  
8           209                662  
9           209                664  
10          209                663  )
```

I have tried the resampling method also, but then i get the data in respective of the time, where the condition of user hitting multiple merchant_store_id is neglected at end time of the hours.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample of the df

Comment: @nixon I have shared the sample, on which the logic is to be written. Wouldn't that be enough? Do you need more data?

Answer (score 0):

if those are datetimes you can filter with the following:

```
filtered_set = set(df[df["stamp_time"]>=x][df["stamp_time"]<=y]["col of interest"])
```

`df[df["stamp_time"]>=x]` filters the df
adding `[df["stamp_time"]<=y]` filters the filtered df
`["merchant_store_id"]` captures just the specified column (series)
and finally `set()` returns the unique list (set)

---

Specific to your code:

```
x = datetime(lowerbound) #pseudo-code
y = datetime(upperbound) #pseudo-code
filtered_set = set(fi_df[fi_df["stamp_time"]>=x][fi_df["stamp_time"]<=y]["col of interest"])
```

Comment: yes those are datetime, but can you show it in my code, where this fits and how it helps ? I also need to append data to a final dataframe for that timeperiod, if the merchant_id.unique is greater than 1

Comment: I dont need to manipulate the final dataframe. I need to optimize the code where it is picking up the values into fdf and then performing something on that df.  like in this case the min time the inner loop of creating new df on indexes would run is 10 times.